# I Want to get the page count using cookie

Tags: php, cookies

I want to get the page count in my index page,using cookie.So far I have done like.Now My question is:If I refresh the page, The browser shows with count 2 and it doesnot increase for next refresh.I don't know what is wrong in my code.Further I want to know how to handle cookie in next page or  shall I can handle cookie in same page? can any one guide please.but this is my requirement.

```
<?php
$cookie = 1;
setcookie("count", $cookie);
if (!isset($_COOKIE['count']))
{
}
else
{
$cookie = ++$_COOKIE['count'];
} 
echo "The Total visit is".$cookie;
?>
```

Comment: What is page count? the number of refreshs?

Comment: Are you trying to get the number of users that visit your site?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958930/cookie-page-counter-in-php

Comment: Yes it shows : The Total visit is :2 and it stops here . for next refresh page stops,I want to get each time new user visit my page. it should count

Comment: is there a reason you chose cookies? There are better alternatives i wil post an answer

Comment: Yes you can do that, but my client  belong to technical person, he wants that in cookie .so He tried this and sent to me. I have used cookie earlier so that I have immediately asked the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use local storage for this as I really dislike cookies, some users block them completely.

**You can setup the echo. To work with this**

Here is what I cam up with: http://jsfiddle.net/azrmno86/

```
// Check browser support
if (typeof(Storage) != "undefined") {

    //check if the user already has visited
    if (localStorage.getItem("count") === "undefined") {
        //set the first time if it dfoes not exisit yet
        localStorage.setItem("count", "1");
    }

    //get current count
    var count = localStorage.getItem("count");

    //increment count by 1
    count++;

    //set new value to storage
    localStorage.setItem("count", count);

    //display value
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = count

} else {

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support";
}
```

**UPDATE After a bit more clarification**

This style uses a .txt file stored on the server. Cookies are not reliable. If someone clears them, your done. if you use variables any server restart will kill your count. Eith use database or this method.

```
<?php
//very important
session_start();
$counter_name = "counter.txt";

// Check if a text file exists. If not create one and initialize it to zero.
if (!file_exists($counter_name)) {
  $f = fopen($counter_name, "w");
  fwrite($f,"0");
  fclose($f);
}

// Read the current value of our counter file
$f = fopen($counter_name,"r");
$counterVal = fread($f, filesize($counter_name));
fclose($f);

// Has visitor been counted in this session?
// If not, increase counter value by one
if(!isset($_SESSION['hasVisited'])){
  $_SESSION['hasVisited']="yes";
  $counterVal++;
  $f = fopen($counter_name, "w");
  fwrite($f, $counterVal);
  fclose($f); 
}

echo "You are visitor number $counterVal to this site";
```

Comment: THis will count each new visit and page refresh also is that correct. can please work with cookie also, what the code i posted. he wants that one

Comment: I have tried this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958930/cookie-page-counter-in-php  this also stops at page 2, in new browser for even for first visit not showing 1 please try it. I could not understand how it marked as an answer

Comment: Cookies are bad. I will post another option.

Comment: You need to clarify EXACTLY what you are trying to count. Each page view by each individual user? or all page views by all users? or each new page visit, once per visit??? Please clarify

Comment: Yes thanks lot for arising this question  to me. once per visit for new visitor while they access the website. it have to show in index page

Comment: I hope you got the requirement, because I want to educate them what I learnt form you. if I show with all possible answer

Comment: I am leaving the office for today so I won't be able to work on it more.

Comment: ok thanks for the solutions. please update by tomorrow In my side also I am trying