# Display my loading screen only when logging in

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a working loading screen that works. The problem is that it displays on every reload. How could i make this only display when i login? I have started to look at somehow calling a function to display it from the login.php ? My concern there is how to call the function from php. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  setTimeout(function(){
      $('body').addClass('loaded');
  }, 700);

});
```

```css
#loader-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#loader-wrapper .loader-section {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 51%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgb(33, 33, 33);
  z-index: 1000;
}

#loader-wrapper .loader-section.section-left {
  left: 0;
}

#loader-wrapper .loader-section.section-right {
  right: 0;
}

#loader {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #3498db;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  z-index: 1001;
}

#loader:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #e74c3c;
  -webkit-animation: spin 3s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 3s linear infinite;
}

#loader:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #f9c922;
  -webkit-animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }
}

.loaded #loader {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.loaded #loader-wrapper {
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s 0.3s ease-out;
}

.no-js #loader-wrapper {
  display: none;
}

.no-js h1 {
  color: #222222;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
 <div id="loader-wrapper">
    <div id="loader"></div>

    <div class="loader-section section-left"></div>
    <div class="loader-section section-right"></div>

</div>


<h1> logged in </h1>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you working with sessions? cookies?

Comment: this is more a backend issue than a front end ... you need to check if you are loggued in using php and decide if you will put the loader or not

Comment: You can make a cookie counter : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958930/cookie-page-counter-in-php and trigger animation only for the first time.

Comment: Create a  Login form and check by writing a condition  whether you are logged or not on refresh if logged in no need to display loader,

Comment: @PatrickMlr Im using sessions yes

Comment: Try to get the session with JS and check if the user is logged in. Then you only need to display the loading thing or not.

Comment: @NawazGhori Already have a login form. So you mean i should check and execute this on the login page instead of the home page?

Comment: @Emoless96 Yes , if  user have entered correct credentials , then navigate to login page with loader

Answer (score 1):

in your situation it's pretty easy to make the loading div shows **only** on the page you want (login)

1- make the loading cover hidden by default in the css and visible if class show is added

```
#loader-wrapper{display:none}
#loader-wrapper.show{display:block}
```

2- and show it only on the log in page by adding the show class. Replace this line

```
<div id="loader-wrapper">
```

into something like this

```
<div id="loader-wrapper" class="<?php if($loginPage) echo "show";?>">
```